# How to let CommonsPoolTargetSource pool size grow as needed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3, spring-aop, pool

I noticed that when there are many requests and the max pool size is reached, other requests wait until a resource is free. How do I set`CommonsPoolTargetSource` such that when it reaches its max pool size, new object instances will be created? The excess resources must also be release after it's used.

Initially, I tried looking for a `minSize` property but found out that `CommonsPoolTargetSource` does not have a `minSize` property. Below is the body of my web.xml:

```
<bean id="simpleBeanTarget" class="com.bean.SimpleBean" scope="prototype">        
</bean>

<bean id="poolTargetSource" class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
    <property name="targetBeanName" value="simpleBeanTarget" />
    <property name="maxSize" value="3" />
    <!-- How do I let the pool grow if more than 3 instances is needed? -->
    <!-- And how do I release the excess instances after usage? -->
</bean>

<bean id="simpleBean" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetSource" ref="poolTargetSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  `<property name="whenExhaustedActionName" value="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" />`

or

```
<property name="whenExhaustedAction">
 <util:constant static-field="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</property>
```

Comment: Hi, Luis! Thanks! I tried setting `whenExhaustedActionName` to `WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW` and my pool is now growing. But my pool did not shrink back to 3 after I used the new object. When will the new object instance be deleted? How do I delete the excess objects if left inactive for a certain period of time?

Comment: Try with timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis and minEvictableIdleTimeMillis properties , by default there is no eviction.

Comment: Thanks! Will be experimenting first on the CommonsPoolTargetSource's properties. :)

Comment: Thanks again! `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` and `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` are responsible for removing the idle objects on the pool.